# Applet's archive-Attribute not supported?

Tags: java, html, applet

While investigating some 404-Statisics I found requests for direct jar-classes.

I deliver all my applets only as .jar-files.

> Note that some browsers do not support the ARCHIVE attribute, so all necessary files should be available unarchived as well.  [>> source](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/applet.html)

My awstats says some classes are requested unarchived.

Can anyone tell me what browser's do not support the archive-attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your source is notoriously unreliable.  Ignore the information.

Of course, the `applet` element was deprecated in HTML 4.01, and now it is best to use the [Deployment Toolkit script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to write whatever element best suits the browser.

As to looking up loose class files, specify the [`codebase-lookup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes) as `false` to limit the search to archives.

Comment: -1 Those requests are logged, the problem is reproducable even if codebase-lookup is set to false. The source is right. A review of the source resolve the problem but does not answer my question.